# Javascript promise event to await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have below code

```
async function callme(){ 
    methods.callfun(x)
             .then(function (res) {
              methods.callfunxx(res)
                     .on("send", function (r) {
                         console.log(r);
                     })
                     .on("error", function (error, r) {
                         console.error(error);
                     });
             });
}
```

And I want to call like this

```
const rr = await callme();
```

but its not waiting to so I am trying to change this in await and tried below

```
 async function callme(){ 
        const res = await methods.callfun(x);
                const response = await methods.callfunxx(res)
                response.on('send',() => {
                    return (`Successfully`)
                });
                response.on('error',() => {
                    return (`error`)
                });
    }
```

Till second await its waiting.. but rest is not working as expected... I am trying to return response as per send/error.

Any help

Thanks

Comment: `methods.callfunxx(res)` probably doesn't return a promise ... and whatever you return in `.on` event handlers goes nowhere and does nothing

Comment: `methods.callfunxx(res)` function probably doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Your current attempt doesn't use promises at all, it just returns a string.

```js
response.on('send', () => {
    return (`Successfully`) // string was returned, but nothing happened afterwards
});
```

Your function is already async, as denoted by the `async` in `async function`.
You can already call it like so:

```js
const rr = await callme();
```

It returns a promise that resolves into `undefined`.

To make it return a `Promise`, that resolves/rejects with the values returned by `methods.callfunxx`, you will need to use the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/), calling `resolve`/`reject` when the event is done, or when an error has occurred.

```js
function callme() {
    const res = await methods.callfun(x);

    const ret_value = methods.callfunxx(res);

    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            ret_value.on("send", resolve).on("error", reject);
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Now, if I'm being honest, I think the question is a duplicate, can someone find the canonical answer to these questions?

Comment: Was the canonical I used the one you had in mind?

Comment: @Bergi Nothing in particular in mind just would've rather seen this directed to an existing answer.